# Solve the differential equation: $(3x^2-y^2)dy-2xdx=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I have the differential equation:
$$(3x^2-y^2) dy - 2x dx=0 $$

I need it to look like the equation: $$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$ in order to apply the integrating factor.

I believe it can be solved using integrating factors because that is the section in the textbook it has come from, but I am totally stumped on how to get $y'$ isolated for the integrating factor.

Is this an integrating factor equation, and if so how do I deal with these types of equations?

Comment: Any first order equation that looks like this can be solved with an integrating factor, but sometimes those integrating factors are hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the differential equation:
> $$(3x^2-y^2) \ dy - 2x \ dx=0 $$

Multiply the integral factor: $e^{-3y}$, then we get:

$$-2xe^{-3y}dx+(3x^2-y^2)e^{-3y}dy=0$$

Now this equation becomes exact.

Comment: Can you demonstrate where this integrating factor comes from?

Comment: Those coefficients are not very complicated, so just observation is enough... for that $3x^2-y^2$ term, after taking $\partial_x$, it will give $6x$, comparing with $-2x$ in front of $dx$, so we just need to make up the factor $-3$, so just use $e^{-3y}$

Answer (score 3):

With $x^2=z$ you could write this as $\dfrac{\mathrm{dz}}{\mathrm{dy}}=3z-y^2$ which is in linear form

Answer (score 1):

$(3x^2-y^2)dy-2xdx=0$

Multiply by M, the integrating factor: $(3x^2-y^2)Mdy-2xMdx=0$

Take $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of the dy term on the left: $6xM+(3x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}$

Take the $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ of the dx term on the right: $-2x\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$

Set them equal: $6xM+(3x^2-y^2)\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}=-2x \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}$

The equation becomes separable if $\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}=0\implies -3=\frac{dM/dy}{M}\implies -3y = \ln M + C\implies M=Ce^{-3y}$ where the partial derivative becomes an ordinary derivative because we are assuming independence of $x$. WLOG we can let $C=1$ since it cancels out.